# What are the ways of both developing a website and having a mobile app version for Android and IOS?

Tags: html, css, web, vuejs3

For context my plan is to start on a project in which the website/app will be built with Vue.js framework and have firebase as the backend.

My idea was to start on the website version first but as i think about it both the website and mobile version will be in heavy use. What i am askig is:

1. Should i opt for a webview to have the website turned into an app for the future?
2. What other good options are there for app development apart from webview for me as i dont have a macbook only a laptop with windows meaning i cant access things like xcode?

I have tried looking into other options and have had chatgpt give me examples and such but i want the opinions of actual developers here. What other options do i have apart from webview in terms of app developement like how could i actually make apps to directly put on the play store and app store